# POWER BI check if I have a value in a column for a unique identifier

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table in which I have this information :

[image]

I want to have this result by a calculated column or measure dax (Power BI).

[image: !enter image description here]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the condition is only on title, then this would work.

```
Calculated_Column = IF( 'Table'[title] = "b", "ok", BLANK() )
```

[image]

```
Measure = IF( SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[title] ) = "b", "ok", BLANK() )
```

In case of measure the results will shrink to only values different than BLANK. Instead of BLANK() you may use a value such as `not ok`.

[image]

Edit. To show the items with no data:
[image]

Comment: thank you but I would like to have this information even on the other lines for example for the ID = 1 and the title "a" --> calculated_column= ok

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Add a calculated column like so:

[image]

Comment: thank you  but I would like to have this information even on the other lines
for example for the ID = 1 and the title "a" --> b= ok

Comment: That's not what you've been asking!

Comment: I was mistaken, sorry !

Comment: Then focus on what you are trying to achive and ask a new question that can be understood by others too.